# Trying to automate data entry on a sap webapp using IE and excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, ui-automation

I am able to log in however, I am not able to select any options from there.

Tried reading on UI Automation however couldn' follow, can someone help to code for click

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "https://website.com/"

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE.document

IE.document.getElementById("j_username").Value = "user"
doc.getElementById("j_password").Value = "pass"
doc.getElementById("logOnFormSubmit").Click

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)
Loop

Dim NewTicketBtn As Object
Set NewTicketBtn = doc.getElementById("__tile0-__component0---landingDetail--aboPanel-2")
NewTicketBtn.Click
```

Comment: What's not working with the existing code? What error mesages are you receiving?

Comment: No error messages but it does not open the page as it would when you mouse click

Comment: Have you added breakpoints to debug the code to see which line of the code is not working? And I think the answer below is reasonable, you could try it. If it is still not working, please provide related html code or website link which can reproduce the issue so that we can investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Read my comments in the macro:

```
Sub test()

  Dim IE As Object
  Dim doc As HTMLDocument
  Dim NewTicketBtn As Object

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.navigate "https://website.com/"
  Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents:  Loop

  Set doc = IE.document

  doc.getElementById("j_username").Value = "user"
  doc.getElementById("j_password").Value = "pass"
  doc.getElementById("logOnFormSubmit").Click

  'This don't work here because the ready state of the IE is allready 'complete'
  'Do While IE.Busy
  'Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)
  'Loop
  '
  'You must set a manual break for a few seconds to load the page after the login
  'If 3 seconds not enough go higher
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

  'Here you can't work anymore with 'doc' because the document in the IE has changed
  Set NewTicketBtn = IE.document.getElementById("__tile0-__component0---landingDetail--aboPanel-2")
  NewTicketBtn.Click
End Sub
```